# Removing items from a observablecollection bound to a datagrid Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, observablecollection

I am getting an error when deleting rows from an observablecollection which is bound to a datagrid in silverlight.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.at at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.RemoveItem(Int32 index)

```
if (GV.orderItemList.Contains(oOrdritem))
    GV.orderItemList.Remove(oOrdritem);
```

The first time, I delete a record, its working fine, the second time, it gives the above exception

[image]

please please please help

Comment: What happens if you bind to a ListBox for example? How many rows do you have when you do the delete? Suspect that it is a problem in the DataGrid... Youi can try and set the DataGrid ItemsSource = null, first, the re-bind it... Also it seems that your row is in edit mode when you do the remove, try it without being in edit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted the problem using the code below:

```
dgOrderItems.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

The row which was currently focused was still in edit mode which was causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RemoveAt instead of Remove, it worked for me in some cases. First you find the index of de item with :

```
int index = collection.IndexOf(item);
```

then you try to remove :

```
collection.RemoveAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a null check: (Or several, not sure what the rest of your code looks like so I'm enforcing everything)

```
if (GV != null && GV.orderItemList != null && oOrdritem != null && GV.orderItemList.Contains(oOrdritem))
    GV.orderItemList.Remove(oOrdritem);
```